# binary search tree c++ searching operation always giving 0;

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

in this BST,the searchbst function is searching perfectly but this function is returning 0 always. It is not giving 5 or 8 as i have programmed it to do so what is the error in code because of which this problem is there

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct bstnode{
bstnode *lchild;
int data;
bstnode *rchild;    
};

void creatbst(bstnode *&T,int k){
    if(T=='\0'){
        T=new(bstnode);
        T->data=k;
        T->lchild='\0';
        T->rchild='\0';
    }
    else if(k<T->data){
        creatbst(T->lchild,k);
    }
    else if(k>T->data){
        creatbst(T->rchild,k);
    }
}

int searchbst(bstnode *T,int k){
    if(T=='\0')
    return 5;
    else{

     if(k<T->data)
    searchbst(T->lchild,k); 

    else if(k>T->data)
    searchbst(T->rchild,k); 

    else
        return 8;
    }
}

int main(){
    bstnode *T;
    T='\0';
    creatbst(T,36);
    creatbst(T,20);
    creatbst(T,75);
    creatbst(T,42);
    creatbst(T,8);
    creatbst(T,31);
    creatbst(T,25);
    creatbst(T,3);
    creatbst(T,80);

    cout<<endl<<"searching for ";
    cout<<searchbst(T,3);
    cout<<endl<<"searching for ";
    cout<<searchbst(T,1);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Put some more trace statements in the code to see what it is doing.  Or step through it one line at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code most likely has undefined behavior: If you don't follow the conditions leading to the `return 5;` or the `return 8;` statements, you call `searchbst()`, ignore its result, and eventually you fall of the function. You probably meant to return the result of `searchbst()`:

```
return searchbst(T->rchild, k);
```

BTW, you have a funny way of writing the null pointer constant: although `'\0'` works, the conventional way is to use `0` or `nullptr` (the latter is the C++11 way).

Comment: thanks! BTW,i will take care of using 0 or nullptr next time :-) leave that thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the return value of the recursive calls.

Replace:

```
if(k<T->data)
  searchbst(T->lchild,k); 
else if(k>T->data)
  searchbst(T->rchild,k); 
else
  return 8;
```

with:

```
if(k < T->data)
  return searchbst(T->lchild, k);
else if(k > T->data)
  return searchbst(T->rchild, k);
else
  return 8;
```